# Read lines from file and store as variable to use in another function before repeating

Tags: python

I'm farily new to python and I'm currently stuck when trying to improve my script. I have a script that performs a lot of operations using selenium to automate a manual task. The scripts opens two pages, searches for an email, fetches data from that page and sends it to another tab. I need help to feed the script a textfile containing a list of email addresses, one line at a time and using each line to search the webpage.  What I need is the following:

1. Open file "test.txt"
2. Read first line in text file and store this value for use in another function.
3. perform function which uses line from text file as its input value.
4. Add "Completed" behind the first line in the text file before moving to the next
5. Move to and read next line i text file, store as variable and repeat from step 3.

I'm not sure how I can do this.

Here is a snippet of my code at the time:

```
def fetchEmail():
    fileName = input("Filename: ")
    fileNameExt = fileName + ".txt" #to make sure a .txt extension is used
        line = f.readline()
        for line in f:
        print(line) # <-- How can I store the value here for use later?
        break

def performSearch():
    emailSearch = driver.find_element_by_id('quicksearchinput')
    emailSearch.send_keys(fetchEmail, Keys.RETURN) <--- This is where I want to be able to paste current line for everytime function is called.
    return main
```

I would appreciate any help how I can solve this.

Comment: This is pretty vague, but I'll do my best. For the future, please read the Stack Overflow help section about how to ask questions.

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry it was vague.

What I'm looking for is how I can read a line from a text file, and store this as a variable that can be called from anywhere else in the script. Everytime it is called however, i need it to read the next line in file

Comment: Can you share the url you are trying to perform this so i can take a look at it

Comment: Hello, no the URL is from a corporate production server. I can not share this unfortunately.

All I need to know is how I can use ".send_keys" to send the value of the line in the text file. Or something similar

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to diagnose your particular issue, since you don't actually provide real code. However, probably one of the following will help you:

- Return the list of all lines from `fetchEmail`, then search for all of them in `send_keys`:

  ```
  def fetchEmail():
      fileName = input("Filename: ")
      fileNameExt = fileName + ".txt"
      with open(fileNameExt) as f:
          return f.read().splitlines()

  def performSearch():
      emailSearch = driver.find_element_by_id('quicksearchinput')
      emailSearch.send_keys(fetchEmail(), Keys.RETURN)
      # ...
  ```
- Yield them one at a time, and look for them individually:

  ```
  def fetchEmail():
      fileName = input("Filename: ")
      fileNameExt = fileName + ".txt"
      with open(fileNameExt) as f:
          for line in f:
              yield line.strip()

  def performSearch():
      emailSearch = driver.find_element_by_id('quicksearchinput')
      for email in fetchEmail():
          emailSearch.send_keys(email, Keys.RETURN)
      # ...
  ```
- I don't recommend using globals, there should be a better way to share information between functions (such as having both of these in a class instance, or having one function call the other like I show above), but here would be an example of how you could save the value when the first function gets called, and retrieve the results in the second function at an arbitrary later time:

  ```
  emails = []

  def fetchEmail():
      global emails
      fileName = input("Filename: ")
      fileNameExt = fileName + ".txt"
      with open(fileNameExt) as f:
          emails = f.read().splitlines()

  def performSearch():
      emailSearch = driver.find_element_by_id('quicksearchinput')
      emailSearch.send_keys(emails, Keys.RETURN)
      # ...
  ```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for laying this out like this. Yielding them one at a time is what I was looking for